# both class and type as a jquery selector

Tags: jquery, css

```
<button class="actionButton default" type="submit"> Save</button>
```

Is there any way to pick both class and type for this button as a jquery selector ?

I tried below one.But not working.

```
var saveBttn=$('.actionButton.default :submit')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var saveBttn=$('.actionButton.default[type=submit]')
```

jQuery API documentation for `:submit`:

> Because :submit is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :submit cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="submit"]
>   instead.

Comment: +1 for mentioning about performance factor.Always must consider performance when we dealing with browser.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the space in the selector:

```
var saveBttn = $('.actionButton.default:submit')
```